# Does this relation partially order partial partitions?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, set-partition

By a partial partition of $X$, I mean a collection of non-empty subsets of $X$ that are disjoint. Given partial partitions $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ of $X$, define $\mathcal{A} \leq \mathcal{B}$ if and only if the following properties hold:

- **Covering Property.** $\bigcup \mathcal{A} \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal{B}$.
- **Inclusion-Exclusion Property** For all $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$, either $A \supseteq B$, or $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

I'm just wondering whether this is a partial order on partial partitions? If so, the least element of this poset is clearly $\emptyset$, and the greatest element is clearly the discrete partition. If this really is a partial order, I'd also be interested to know whether it has meets and joins, too.

Comment: I think I see what's going on with this structure: $\mathcal A\leq \mathcal B$ means that $\mathcal B$ is a refinement of $\mathcal A$ on the support of $\mathcal A$, but it's also allowed to cover extra elements. Am I getting this right? I think in this case (a) yes it is a poset, and moreover (b) it is isomorphic to the partition lattice on $X\cup\{*\}$, and hence has meets and joins. If that's enough of a push to get you over the hump, let me know, otherwise I'll write something up sooner or later :)

Comment: @EricNathanStucky, yes, your intuition is pretty much what I was going for. Also: wow, is this really isomorphic to the partition lattice over an extra point? That's wonderful, and also trivializes the rest of the question.